# Javascript for three.js controls

Tags: javascript, mouse, three.js

I'm trying to make a little game in three.js.
The controlling javascript code is below:

```
window.onmouseover = function (ev) {
    down = true;
    sx = ev.clientX;
    sy = ev.clientY;
};
window.onmouseout = function () {
    down = false;
};
window.onmousemove = function (ev) {
    if (down) {
        var dx = ev.clientX - sx;
        var dy = ev.clientY - sy;
        camera.rotation.y += -dx / 100;
        //camera.rotation.x += -dy/100;
        sx += dx;
        sy += dy;
    }
}
```

My question is: How can i prevent mouse from going off the window and continue its movement?

I have an idea about repositioning it in the center in every tick so it won't move that far but i don't know how to do it either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Pointer Lock API](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/Pointer-Lock-API-Brings-FPS-Games-to-the-Browser) isn't well-supported, but that's how you do it.